# How do you load a XGBoost model saved using dump_model?

Tags: python, xgboost

Seems that there is no answer to this question. Yet in the [**documentation**](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) is is listed as a possible way to save the model.

```
dump_model(fout, fmap='', with_stats=False, dump_format='text')
```

After hours of searching I have found no answer of how to recover my model. And training it again is a not an option. It took more than 10 days of training.

So if anybody can give me an answer (that does not include training the model again) I will kindly appreciate. **The model is already saved using dump_model.** So please focus on that.

When I try to use `get_dump()` I receive a cryptic message

```
> xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [05:27:16]
> C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\xgboost-win64_release_1.1.0\src\learner.cc:506:
> Check failed: mparam_.num_feature != 0 (0 vs. 0) : 0 feature is
> supplied.  Are you using raw Booster interface?
```

Comment: ```load_model(fout)``` does not work?

Comment: @Wavy No. You can try it yourself. It gives you `OSError: [WinError -529697949] Windows Error 0xe06d7363`  Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not possible without hand written parser** according to this [**Github answer**](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/5817). It's for visualization like plotting the trees, exporting to other formats for other libraries etc. **But not for saving a working model.**

This caveat is not included in the documentation for some obscure reason.

**Bummer.**